# How do force rmarkdown under Shiny server to use alternative R

Tags: r, r-markdown, shiny-server

I want to have two versions of R on my system. I want rmarkdown under shiny server to use /usr/bin/R which it does when I chmod 000 /usr/local/bin/R. Otherwise, I get an error. I do not want trouble with the error right now, nor do I want to remove /usr/local/bin/R. Can someone tell me how to correctly configure a PATH or environment component so that shiny server uses the R binary that I desire (usr/bin/R)?

Answer (score 0):

In Shiny Server Pro, there's a configuration option for this: http://rstudio.github.io/shiny-server/latest/#r_path

In the Open Source version, you may just need to resort to adjusting `PATH`.

Comment: Yes, I understand. the question ask HOW this is performed.